# Timeline for Project

Tags: timeline

Looking for a way to create a project timeline that:

1. Shows what needs to be done when (theoretically)
2. Easily shareable with client

Keep in mind that the client wants: "I need to know where we are at on the project"

Comment: Welcome to PMSE! This is a possible duplicate of [Which tool do you use for creating good looking project timelines?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/2995/which-tool-do-you-use-for-creating-good-looking-project-timelines)

Answer (score 1):

If he (client) wants to basically know where you are at on the project you can make one **weekly** product burndown chart. I will give you one template [image: You need to have a good backlog and deadline for a project.]

Good luck

Answer (score -1):

[GANTT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gantt_chart) charts are the most effective ways to communicate project schedule.